# How to construct a pattern that escapes all metacharacters in java?

Tags: java

I want to match pair of words where one of them changes constantly (loop over an array of strings). The problem is that this word may contain metacharacters and I don't know which ones, so escaping them manually is a bit problem. Is there a way to construct a pattern of a string that already escapes all its metacharacters in java?

Comment: You will need to either know what you want to escape or what you do not want to escape if you want to use regular expressions.

Comment: Do you mean _escape_? Could you give an example of input and expected output?

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "[java] escape special characters in string". You'd be amazed how many times every imaginable variant of this question has been posted.

Comment: @Thomas: yes, sorry for my English. I appreciate your corrections, thanks.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I already did that... I found questions about escaping specific metachars in determined words but not that I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are specifically talking about regular expressions, as implied by ‘matching words’, then the method you want is [Pattern.quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29).

In the more general sense, there is no way to automagically escape ‘metacharacters’ when you don't know what your target syntax is. In principle any character could have special non-literal meaning, and the way to escape it is completely dependent on the target syntax. In regular expressions, it's prefixing with a backslash, but for your question it is not clear whether you're talking about regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You have a strings with meta-characters, but you don't know what meta-characters exactly. But in some way you know what meta-character is.

If you know all meta-characters which can appear in string, just list they in group: `[\*abc\$\.\,\s]` (this group means in regexp that you can meet one of this characters, for example star, a, b, c, bucks ($), point, comma, whitespace). Also you can use `^` (`[^....]`) to invert logic.